# Matplotlib 2D heatmap style

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a 2D plot of 2 variables with each point on the plot having a colour that is controlled by a third variable. I'd also like to interpolate between the data points. I can't think of the correct plot type to use as most only take two or one that is a function of the other two.

Comment: have you looked [here](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#images_contours_and_fields)? `imshow`, `pcolormesh` and `contourf` all do what I think you are asking

Comment: Yeah that was the first place I look. It's having to use 2D arrays for the x,y,z arguments that's tripping me up.

Comment: Would something like this achieve your aim? http://simonbiggs.net/electronfactors

Comment: Maybe if you share am example of your 3 variables, including the shape of the arrays, that would help